# Mysql normalization? Or another way?

Tags: c#, mysql

After reading up on some normalization, it seems I am not quite grasping the concept.

What I am attempting to do is create a table that holds information for an item raffle.

So information for the item is ItemName, and Defindex.

After that, I need to have the "tickets" for the raffle, and to which user they went to. I want to limit the number of tickets sold.

So TicketA, TicketB, TicketC, TicketD.

Is there a query that I can use to insert a player name into TicketA if it's not full, or TicketB if A is full, so on until all tickets are sold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample to get you started: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c925/1/0)

Setup the basic tables to keep track of raffles and tickets.

```
CREATE TABLE Raffle
(
     Id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,WinnerLimit INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RaffleTicket
(
     Id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,RaffleId BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,UserId BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

Setup a view to determine whether a raffle has any tickets left.

```
CREATE VIEW RaffleStatus
AS
    SELECT Id AS RaffleId,
           CASE WHEN EXISTS
           (
                SELECT 1
                FROM RaffleTicket rt
                WHERE rt.RaffleId = r.Id
                GROUP BY rt.RaffleId
                HAVING COUNT(rt.RaffleId) = r.WinnerLimit
           )
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0
           END AS SoldOut
    FROM Raffle r;
```

Create a procedure to prevent overselling tickets. Note this probably isn't safe for multithreaded use.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRaffleTicket (IN userId BIGINT, IN raffleId BIGINT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RaffleTicket(UserId, RaffleId)
    SELECT userId, raffleId
    FROM RaffleStatus rs
    WHERE rs.RaffleId = raffleId
    AND rs.SoldOut = 0;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: In your examples. It is giving me an error for the View, unknown column "RaffleId". I think I have pinpointed this to the SELECT Id, RaffleId portion, as there is no RaffleId in the Raffle table. There is only Id, Name, and Winnerlimit.

Comment: Nevermind. I looked into the Fiddle and saw the changes made. Thank you. This gives me a great example to work with.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Also please note that there are no foreign keys setup because this is meant as an example.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to limit the number of tickets sold.

That is business logic, not something that should reside in your database.

What if you want to query all raffles user X has attended? `select * from raffles where ticketA = 'UserX' or ticketB = 'UserX' or ticketC = 'UserX'`...

Just normalize it and check the ticket count from code.

Comment: I understand that it should be done in code for that. But I can't figure out how to structure the database. There could potentially be hundreds of thousands of people in the database. Only a few raffles will be active at a given time.

Would it be best to create a new table for every raffle, and do it that way instead?

As far as the normalize, I don't quite grasp the concept of it. Should I create a table that holds the a list of all the raffles, and then another table that is linked to the raffle table that holds the tickets? How would a query be performed on that?

Answer (score 0):

One table of people, one of tickets, one of raffles.
Each ticket has the ID of the person and of the raffle.

As the previous answer, beyond that is business logic that shouldn't be in the DB. At most, you should "release" a batch of tickets for a raffle by creating them in the tickets table and then when a person wants to buy one you take the first ticket with the correct raffle ID and a null person ID.